# How to read Riverpod provider outside Widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, state-management

This is an ecommerce based app. Im maintaining a map of products viewed by user using provider. When app moves to background, I want to access the provider and make a network call to update the values.

I tried to use provider container

```
final globalProviderContainer = ProviderContainer();
```

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      
      final views = globalProviderContainer.read(
        viewsCounterNotifierProvider,
      );
      print(views);
      performBackgroundAction();
    }
```

This only returns empty value for the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line in `initState`

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
```

Then do like this:

```
  @override
     void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
     super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
     final views = globalProviderContainer.read(
    viewsCounterNotifierProvider,
  );
  print(views);
  performBackgroundAction();
 }
```

The other option you can adopt is to use isolate like

```
void backgroundTask() {
  final globalProviderContainer = ProviderContainer();
final views = globalProviderContainer.read(
    viewsCounterNotifierProvider,
  );
  print(views);
  performBackgroundAction();

}
```

and then call this in isolate

```
@override
     void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
     super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
     FlutterIsolate.spawn(backgroundTask);
}
```

To use isolate, use [flutter_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) package

Comment: For more clarity: The issue is my usage of providerContainer does'nt successfully read the provider and the value remains empty.. Im able to execute other un-related code to provider when app moves to background.

Comment: So the issue is with how you are implementing the provider. Try to add the print statement and see if the data is flowing. You should also initilize provider in initstate